# DependencyProperty Strangeness

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, observablecollection

I've put together a WPF application using `ObservableCollection` and `Dependency Properties` which is cool because I just have to add an item to the `ObservableCollection` and it shows up automatically, e.g. I display the objects in the collection as boxes on the screen in a wrappanel, each box showing its `Title`.

So then I wanted to have each item show not only its `Title` plus a prefix or suffix, but the Dependency Object property doesn't even seem to be used. I can put a break point on it and it is never reached.

Can anyone enlighten me why, if I add text to my outgoing property, that that text is never seen? I have read that the value is actually "stored not in the object but in WPF" but I don't understand what that means.

Why is the text **this text will NOT be seen** never output by the dependency object?

```
public class ApplicationItem : DependencyObject
{

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue("this text will NOT be seen: " + TitleProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TitleProperty, "this text will be seen: " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TitleProperty is not a normal property but a dependency property so if you want to retrieve the value of your TitleProperty you have to do :

```
var title = (string)GetValue(TitleProperty);
```

In WPF guideline, the public property to access a Dependency Property is not called by WPF and the binding engine (not necessary). This public property is only used by your code behind. So you MUST not add code logic inside your public property.

But you can use a FrameworkPropertyMetadata when you register your DP and provide a CoerceValueCallback to change the setted value.

You can also use a IValueConverter with your binding.

Comment: ok but I am retrieving it from XAML, e.g. <...Property="Text" Value="{Binding Title}"/> so I just have access to the public property "Title"

Comment: Edvward, in WPF guideline, the public property to access a Dependency Property is not called by WPF and the binding engine (not necessary). This public property is only used by your code behind.
So you MUST not add code logic inside your public property.

Comment: If you don't believe me, try to bind something to a dependency property without writing a public property, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work for me:

```
public string Title
{
    get 
    { 
        string value = (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); 
        return value + " postfix";
    }
    set 
    { 
        SetValue(TitleProperty, "Prefix " + value); 
    }
}
```

Is there a reason why you are attempting to modify the value when retrieving it rather than just modifying it when the value is set?

Comment: hmm, that doesn't work for me, it just returns the value but not " postfix" at the end. When I set the property I want to prefix it with a property of the object (Kind) but it is not set at that point, so I can add text but not property values of the object, equally odd.